# How to avoid fetching a data that was previously fetched (sqlite3 & python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I use a loop query, and I want to avoid fetching data that was previously fetched.

The best idea that I came up with is to make an ever-expanding blacklist of the data that was fetched, and remove data that was blacklisted every time that I fetch.

I've managed to do so by adding every data that was fetched successfully to a blacklist (called 'allWords'):

```
allWords.Extend(fetchedData)
```

And then fetching all the items which are not in 'allWords':

```
c.execute("SELECT formatted FROM dictionary WHERE formatted LIKE ('__A_')")
words=[item[0] for item in c.fetchall() if item[0] not in allWords]
return words
```

But this way I still fetch all the date, is there any smart way to do so?

Comment: if feasible, put records  into  a dictionary on the client-side . this only overwrites old records instead of creating new ones.

Comment: Can we see this *loop query* and *blacklisting* attempt? Current and desired results are helpful too.